# Where do I start for java script code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is is when an Input value of 1-12 is entered, the color will fill into the corresponding boxes. 1-4 will be red, 5-9 will be yellow and 10-12 will be green, the gray box will be a reset button. I'm going thru my JavaScript book and have a little hard time trying to figure out how to go about this. A little insight on how to tackle this would great help and appreciated.

```css
body {
  background-color: #006699; 
}
#fm {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 20.7%;
}
#wrap {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
#green{
  /*background-color: #00ff00; Color Reference */
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
#yellow{
  /*background-color: #ffff00; */
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 1 );
}
#red{
  /* background-color: #ff0000; Color Reference */
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
#gray{
  /* background-color: #c0c0c0; Color Reference */
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(192,192,192,1);
}
#green:active {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#yellow:active {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

#red:active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#gray:active {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Square </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="square.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="green"></div>
      <div id="yellow"></div>
      <div id="red"></div>
      <div id="gray"></div>
    </div>
    <form id="fm">
      <b>Input value from 1-12</b> <br>
      <input type="text" id="inputvalue" name="value">
      </br>
    </form>
  </body>
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="square.js">
</html>
```

Comment: `link` is not for javascript - use a `script` tag.

Comment: You might as well put the script in the end of </body> tag, not after it. What does square.js do? Provide contents of your javascript file.

Answer (score 2):

Use `script` tag to link your external script.

Change

```
<link rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="square.js">
```

TO

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="square.js"></script>
```